# I can access my WAMP server on any computer on network A but not on network B

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, lan, wamp

I have set up a Wamp server on my computer and I can access it using both my IP and computer name on network A.  However, when I connect **both** computers (also tried on my phone) to network B, I can't connect to my Wamp server.

In case it has something to do with security, network A (works) uses WPA, network B (doesn't work) uses WPA2-PSK.

I'd like to put emphasis that when it worked on network A, all devices I tested were connected to network A.  When I tried it on network B, prior to trying it, I reconnected all devices to network B and restarted Wamp.

I'm using WampServer 3.1.7.  The only configuration change I've done was *Require local* > *Require all granted* in httpd-vhosts.conf in order to access my server from other devices.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?  Is there some kind of workaround?
Thanks!

Edit: I am able to ping between the two computers.

Comment: Do you have routes between both networks?

Comment: Yes, I could ping using the IP and names on both networks.  It turns out my firewall was the one blocking.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to use Wamp Stack (fix all issues like: mySQL corrupted if shutdown server suddenly, or the table error, etc.).

If you are using wamp stack, it will be fixed by open port in Firewall (Control Panel). It work for my case (detail how to open port 80: https://tips.alocentral.com/open-tcp-port-80-in-windows-firewall/)

Answer (score -1):

I deactivated my firewall and it worked!